# Swipe using TableView library

Tags: android

I am using evrencoskun TableView library in my project (java android).
https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView

Is there some way to enable row swipe using this library?
(something, looks like picture attached)
[image]

Comment: Think, something will be useful from this: https://github.com/nemanja-kovacevic/recycler-view-swipe-to-delete